# Why is adult mango tree thinning, and leaves browning and dying?

Tags: plant-care

Starting around 6 months ago the tree began I feel to be less full, now the leaves are browning and dying entirely.

Top of the tree appears to be doing better, lower part of the tree is more shaded if that could have anything to do with it.

The tree has not been fertilized in at least 2 years.

Thank you for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anything relevant going on on the other side of the fence? The roots of the tree will be as much on the other side as your side. Look for digging, soil disturbance, fertilizer/pesticide application.